# Deny access to css/ and js/ folders or redirect/rewrite to index.html with htaccess

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to know how I can **deny** the **access** to specific **folders** with htaccess.

I tried it with a **redirect**:

```
Redirect 301 /css/ http://localhost/ [NC,L]
```

But that brakes anything on the site.

Also tried with a **rewrite**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

but still not a good solution.

Comment: If someone goes to one of your pages, they're probably going to need to access those css and js folders, any links to anything in css/js will be requested by the browser

Comment: What do you want that for anyway? Just deny folder listing if you don’t want people to see what other files you might have laying around in these folders.

Comment: Yeah basically if a user type in example.net/css he shall be redirected to the index.html I don't want to let him see what is in the folder. It's really just a cosmetic aspect fore sure! =)

Comment: As I said, deny folder listing, and everything is fine.

Comment: Alright doing it with Options -Indexes  now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding

```
Options -Indexes
```

to the htaccess and now the whole access to any folder is forbidden. Actually not what I wanted but anyways working.